# Using a String in Stored in Shared Preferences in Card View Layout

Tags: java, android, xml, sharedpreferences

I would like to use a string value stored in Shared Preferences in a Card View. I know most likely I can not add it to the XML layout directly. If that is the case, what is the java that adds this string to the existing TextView in the XML layout below.

My XML layout for the Card View:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- A CardView that contains 2 TextViews -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view_results"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="375dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#FFFFFF"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="@string/heading"
                android:textColor="#050505"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/value"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/title_text_body"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="<String stored in Shared Preferences>"
                android:textColor="#050505"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Since you have TextView, just set it to the text of one of the TextView using the `setText` function?

Comment: I should have thought of that! So obvious.

Comment: Well, I didn't expect it to be something that simple. Added it as an answer since it seemed to be what you needed. Cheers! :)

Comment: I know your answer is correct because my placeholder code used setText(). I deleted the placeholder code to make way for the actual code which has ended up needing what I deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display the string value stored in Shared Preferences,

set it to one of your TextView using the [setText(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.widget.TextView.BufferType)) function! :)